# Firebase Cloud Firestore freezes app on insert

Tags: android, firebase, insert, google-cloud-firestore

I'm facing a strange problem. When I try to add data to my database, the app completely freezes. I've debugged the Firestore routines, and it seems to get stuck on the `add(Object)` method.

This is the code from which I call to insert the data:

```
public void addArmaOficial(Arma data) {
        if (data != null)
            db.collection(Constants.COLLECTION_BASE)
                    .document(Constants.COLLECTION_ARMAS)
                    .collection(Constants.COLLECTION_OFIARM)
                    .add(data)   ///< It get's stucked here
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, R.string.accionexistosa, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            ctx.finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, R.string.addarmaoficialtoast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
        else
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Los datos son nulos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I don't understand why this is happening. There's a little extract of the class "Arma":

```
public class Arma extends Equipo implements Parcelable {
    private String dano;
    private String tipo_dano;
    private ArrayList<Prop_Arma> propiedades;
    private String categoria_princ;
    private String categoria_secun;
    private String notas;
    private float distancaimed, distanciamax;
    private int mods;
///< Constructor, getters and setters, and parcelable implementation done automatically
}
```

And the "Prop_Arma" class:

```
public class Prop_Arma implements Parcelable {
    private String nombre;
    private boolean dano_var;
    private String descripcion;
    private boolean distancia;
    private boolean grande, muygrande, gigante, gargantuesca;
///< The same as previous, constructors, getters and setters, and the Parcelable implementation done automatically
}
```

The thing is that it gets stucked and say no error. Is like is running something, but I don't know what. Also, i've done the timestamps update in my code, so I don't think that could be the problem.

### UPDATE 1

This is the code from where it's been called the method `addArmaOficial(Arma data)`:

```
public void Guardar(boolean flag) {
        if (arma_nueva.getPropiedades() == null && !flag) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.nopropmessage)
                    .setTitle(R.string.nopropmesstit);

            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            Toast.makeText(CrearArma.this, "Operación cancelada...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.continuar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            Guardar(true);
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            arma_nueva.setNombre(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombre)).getText().toString());
            if(!Objects.equals(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.peso)).getText().toString(), ""))
                arma_nueva.setPeso(Float.parseFloat(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.peso)).getText().toString()));
            if(!Objects.equals(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.costePC)).getText().toString(), ""))
                arma_nueva.setPc(Integer.parseInt(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.costePC)).getText().toString()));
            if(!Objects.equals(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.costePP)).getText().toString(), ""))
                arma_nueva.setPp(Integer.parseInt(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.costePP)).getText().toString()));
            if(!Objects.equals(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.costePO)).getText().toString(), ""))
                arma_nueva.setPo(Integer.parseInt(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.costePO)).getText().toString()));
            arma_nueva.setDano(((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.dano)).getSelectedItem().toString());
            arma_nueva.setTipo_dano(tip_dano_spin.getSelectedItem().toString());
            arma_nueva.setCategoria_princ(cats_spin.getSelectedItem().toString());
            arma_nueva.setCategoria_secun(tips_spin.getSelectedItem().toString());
            if(!Objects.equals(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.distmed)).getText().toString(), ""))
                arma_nueva.setDistancaimed(Float.parseFloat(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.distmed)).getText().toString()));
            if(!Objects.equals(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.distmax)).getText().toString(), ""))
                arma_nueva.setDistanciamax(Float.parseFloat(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.distmax)).getText().toString()));
            if(!Objects.equals(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.mods)).getText().toString(), ""))
                arma_nueva.setMods(Integer.parseInt(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.mods)).getText().toString()));
            DBConnector db = new DBConnector(this);
            db.addArmaOficial(arma_nueva);
        }
    }
```

This is inside a class declared as:

```
public class CrearArma extends AppCompatActivity {
///...
}
```

Comment: Does `e.printStackTrace();` return something? Have you tried to use `set()` method insted of `add()`?

Comment: @AlexMamo e.printStackTrace() doesn't return something, but I'll try with set() instead of add(). I'll tell you the result.

Comment: Ok, keep me poested.

Comment: @AlexMamo Nothing. Just nothing. I also have tried to clean+rebuild project, invalidate caches and restart, uninstall the app and reinstall, but nothing works...

Comment: Is something written in the database?

Comment: Yes, and it can read it well. It's strange...

Comment: From where are you calling this `addArmaOficial` method?

Comment: I've added the code

Answer (score 0):

Well, i finally found the problem!

It wasn't firebase, it wasn't how it was sended, it just was a resource that can't be found. Just some strings that i've replaced with non-strings-file strings and it works.